# Checking state of NSButton Checkbox on Xcode for macOS apps swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, checkbox, nsbutton

I have an NSButton Checkbox on Xcode using Swift 3 for making macOS applications. I'm trying to check the state (whether its on or off). Some options I have found, such as :
    `if ([Switch1 state] == NSOnState) { //CODE}` When I do this, it tells me to inout a comma after "Switch 1". Is this right, or is this version of code too old for Swift 3?

```
`@IBOutlet weak var Switch1: NSButton!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if ([Switch1 state] == NSOnState) {
        print("On")
    }  
  }`
```

UPDATE: For those looking at this later as a reference, the correct line was `if (Switch1.state == NSOnState) {//CODE}`

Comment: Can you show up some code ?

Comment: The check line is Objective-C but the way to check the state is correct and even in ObjC you can use dot notation (`Switch1.state`).

Comment: I have updated the contents of the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Xcode 9 Swift 4**
I found this post which solved the problem for me.
["'NSOffState' is unavailable in Swift"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181953/nsoffstate-is-unavailable-in-swift)

(In short, the `NSOnState` is replaced with `.on`)